# Trimming a date off a string sometimes php

Tags: php

I have strings that sometimes look like this `8:30AM12/14/15` (The dates at the end can vary) and sometimes look like this `8:30AM`. My problem is that I need them all to look like the later example, but I can't figure out how to trim the date off the end of these every time they show up.

I know of functions that can remove a specific amount of letters at the end of a string, but that doesn't work for me as sometimes the strings are fine. This is a result of about a year of user data entry with mistakes. I am rewriting the software we are using and have implemented much better data entry validation but I am trying to convert old entries into the new software.

Comment: string -> datetime object -> output in whatever format you want. e.g. [date_create_from_string](http://php.net/date_create_from_string)

Comment: Use `preg_replace`. If it doesn't find a match for the regular expression, it won't do anything.

Comment: @Barmar the problem with that is that the dates can vary. I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preg_replace` to return just the time part of the string.

```
$time = preg_replace('/^(\d{1,2}:\d{2}[AP]M).*/', $1, $time_date);
```